# IF values dont open how they should

Tags: javascript

When I chose value 8.2.2 and value 7.1.2 it opens me 8_shema_sv_DUO500.html and that is working perfectly below is example

```
if((aa8 == '8.2.2') && (aa7 == '7.1.2'))
{
    window.open("http://www.mysite.com/scheme/8_shema_sv_DUO500.html");
```

But when I want to chose Scheme 30 where values are  3.1.1, 5.1.3, 8.2.2, 6.2.1, 7.1.2 it opens again `8_shema_sv_DUO500.html` But in code is defined to open `30_shema_zs_hkb_sv_AT1000_DUO500` Someone have idea what am I doing wrong? Below is code from that scheme 30

```
if((aa3 == '3.1.1') && (aa5 == '5.1.3') && (aa8 == '8.2.2') && (aa6 == '6.2.1') && (aa7 == '7.1.2'))
{
    window.open("http://www.mysite.com/scheme/30_shema_zs_hkb_sv_AT1000_DUO500.html");
}
```

Comment: Can I view the whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **if-else if** instead of using two if blocks.

Comment: Am I supposed to laught here? Lol. Wait.

Comment: I can't see the if blocks in View Source

Comment: yes you can there are from 404 line to 600 line

Comment: I really can't. I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6ALrA/ here you can se?

Comment: Yes. Wait for a moment. I'm editing your fiddle.

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ALrA/1/

Comment: Also, if you want, I can try simplifying your code. That code gave my eyes a hard time.

Comment: Thanks i accepted your anwser

Comment: If you want to you can :D btw do you ever feel like superman? Because you just saved my life :D

Comment: Was this problem gonna get you killed? If so, it's my pleasure to be superman. I'm trying to simplify the code a bit. It really did hurt my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Your test (aa8 == '8.2.2') && (aa7 == '7.1.2') is executed first and is right. So your second test is not executed before opening your 8_shema_sv_DUO500.html page.

Comment: And can i somehow change that? Because i must have 8.2.2 and 7.1.2 in schema 30 and in schema 8

Comment: Use the code below :

`if((aa8 == '8.2.2') && (aa7 == '7.1.2'))
{
 if((aa3 == '3.1.1') && (aa5 == '5.1.3') && (aa6 == '6.2.1')) {
  window.open("http://www.mysite.com/scheme/30_shema_zs_hkb_sv_AT1000_DUO500.html");
 } else  {
  window.open("http://www.mysite.com/scheme/8_shema_sv_DUO500.html");
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Since your first condition is fullfilled both times this is fired!

```
if((aa8 == '8.2.2') && (aa7 == '7.1.2'))
{
    if((aa3 == '3.1.1') && (aa5 == '5.1.3') && (aa6 == '6.2.1'))
    {
        window.open("http://www.mysite.com/scheme/30_shema_zs_hkb_sv_AT1000_DUO500.html");
    }else
    {
        window.open("http://www.mysite.com/scheme/8_shema_sv_DUO500.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: And can i somehow change that?